# Gulp autoprefixer is installed but not prefixing

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, gulp, autoprefixer

I tried to install gulp autoprefixer following a tutorial, however, the autoprefixer is not prefixing. I searched for solutions for hours, but still cannot get it work. I am certain that there should be prefix added to my CSS file, since I use the 'display: flex' property. Below are the steps of my installation:

1. npm init
2. sudo npm install gulp -g
3. touch gulpfile.js
4. npm install gulp --save -div
5. npm install gulp-autoprefixer --save -dev
6. edit the gulpfile.js shown below and execute it:

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');

gulp.task('autoprefix', function() {
  gulp.src('test.css')
  .pipe(autoprefixer())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('prefix'))

});
```

I think I successfully installed the gulp-autoprefixer because I can see it in the depencencies in the package.json file shown below:

```html
{
  "name": "autoprefixer",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.html",
  "dependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^9.3.1",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^6.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}
```

The execution of gulpfile.js output a .css file in the newly created 'prefix' directory, however, there was no prefix added, the content looked exactly the same as my original .css file. I have no idea why the autoprefixer does not work, please leave a comment if you have any idea, thanks!

Comment: Do you know for sure that you're using CSS attributes that require a prefix? Something like `flex-box` or `grid` should still get prefixes, stuff like `border-radius` should not. Paste you're CSS in [the autoprefixer demo](http://autoprefixer.github.io/) to see what the output should look like.

Comment: Yes, I use flex-box. This is one of my attributes for a class: .container{ display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column; flex-wrap: wrap;}

Comment: Did you try your code in the demo? Compare that output to your Gulp output. I would guess your script is working. But you may need to [add browser targets](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer#browsers).

Comment: Thank you so much Bryce, you are right about it. It worked after I add the browser target!